# Cakephp Input Date to Database

Tags: forms, date, cakephp, input

I'm trying to take a date from the user and I can't get my date validation to pass. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
//model code
public $validate = array(
    'expiry' => array(
        'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
        'message' => 'Invalid date format'
    )
);

// controller
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Entry->create();

        if ($this->Entry->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your contest entry has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your entry.'));
    }
}

// view code
echo $this->Form->input('expiry', array('type' => 'date', 'dateFormat' => 'YMD'));
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: should the dateFormat in the view code be in all caps?

Comment: An example ymd date is today = '20140814'

Comment: have you debugged the actual data being submitted to verify it's in the format you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what format I should expect it to be in. How do I know what format to insert into the database and which variable holds what's going into the database? (thank you for your patience. I'm very new to CakePhp)

Comment: @Katelyn - it doesn't really matter what format you expect it - debug to find out what's submitting, then determine if you think it should, in your mind, pass your validation rule, and if you think the submitted data should pass, paste it into your question so we have something to work with.  It's just as like something else is wrong, and NOTHING is being submitted for that field... until we know that, there's not much to help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. Mostly my solution was to add this in my Model:

```
function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    // covert the expiry date string to a valid format for the database
    $this->data['Entry']['expiry'] = 
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s',
            strtotime(
                $this->data['Entry']['expiry']));
}
```